# File system full - except it's not

Tags: filesystems, solaris

I've a Solaris 8 box which is reporting that a file system is full:

```
db% tail -2 /var/adm/messages
Nov 22 08:32:27 db ufs: [ID 845546 kern.notice] NOTICE: alloc: /u03: file system full
Nov 22 08:34:51 db last message repeated 12 times
```

But df says it's not out of free blocks, and it's not out of free inodes either:

```
db% df -k /u03
Filesystem            kbytes    used   avail capacity  Mounted on
/dev/md/dsk/d6       282330903 254957403 24550191    92%    /u03
db% df -o i /u03
Filesystem             iused   ifree  %iused  Mounted on
/dev/md/dsk/d6      29663278 4230866    88%   /u03
```

So I thought perhaps some process is holding open file descriptor(s) to 20+GB of deleted files.  But lsof, sorting by size, reports nothing over 2GB, and that's a legitimate file:

```
db% lsof /u03 | sort -n +6
COMMAND     PID     USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE   SIZE/OFF     NODE NAME
[...]
oracle     1257   oracle  278u  VREG   85,6 2097160192  9685782 /u03/oradata/(redacted)/data/foo_tab_14.dbf
db%
```

I'd appreciate any pointers to any other resource save free blocks and inodes whose exhaustion can fill up a file system, or some other way to "hide" used blocks/inodes, or any other idea anyone has.  Rebooting this box or shutting down oracle is not a valid investigative option.

**Edit**: Khaled, I couldn't at the time.  I can't post the output, because one of the DBAs has freed up about 4GB which means the machine can continue functioning, and if I "fill it up" again as a test, things will break.  But this is the second time in 24 hours it's got to about 92% full and "filled up" (as in, new files can't be created, and `/var/adm/messages` reports "file system full"), and yes, when it happens it definitely breaks the creation or extension of files on that FS.

Comment: Can you create files under the full partitions or is it just an annoying message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the `nbfree` value with

```
fstyp -v | head -18
```

If that says some low value, [this blog post I found](http://www.leidinger.net/blog/2011/04/19/solaris-ufs-full-while-df-shows-plenty-of-free-spaceinodes/) might help you. I quote the beginning of the post:

> At work we have a Solaris 8 with a UFS which told the appli­ca­tion
>   that it can not cre­ate new files. The df com­mand showed plenty if
>   free inodes, and there was also enough space free in the FS. The
>   rea­son that the appli­ca­tion got the error was that while there
>   where still plenty of frag­ments free, no free block was avail­able
>   any­more. You can not cre­ate a new file only with frag­ments, you
>   need to have at least one free block for each new file.
>
> To see the num­ber of free blocks of a UFS you can call “fstyp -v |
>   head -18″ and look at the value behind “nbfree”.

Comment: By the way, I've had almost identical situation for JFS3 filesystem once.

Comment: Janne, you're a star, I suspect this is it.  Next time we go "FS full" I've got the command sitting at a prompt, ready to run.  News as it's made.

Comment: Great! Let me know how this goes :)

Comment: Ugh, what a time for my DBAs to get a conscience, and start clearing up the FS wholesale.  From about 900,000 free blocks when I first looked, it's now up to just north of three million.  Although that means I can't confirm your hypothesis, the nature of the increase makes me fairly sure you're right, so I'm going to accept your answer now; if at some point the DBAs let the error happen again, and nbfree is not zero or very close to it, I'll come back and reopen the issue.  I hope that's OK.